# Teechart C#:How to find shapeindex of country in different regions?

Tags: c#-4.0, teechart

How to find shape index of countries in different regions.
Teechart for .net

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please expand the question if that's not what you are asking for.

Knowing the name of a country, you can loop the `Labels` array to find the index for that shape. Ie:

```
private void CreateMap()
{
  World world1 = new World(tChart1.Chart);
  world1.FillSampleValues();

  for (int i = 0; i < world1.Count; i++)
  {
    if (world1.Labels[i] == "Spain")
    {
      world1.Colors[i] = Color.Red;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```